# How to reference a cell on another worksheet by the table title

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel has multiple worksheets.

The plan is the table on my "main" worksheet will reference data from another worksheet - I believe quite a common thing to do

I'm trying to build the syntax dynamically, referencing a string on my table for the worksheet name. For example, if a cell had the word `purchases`, I'd also have a worksheet called purchases.

In this case, I have the following table in my "main" worksheet

```
      A            
1   purchases    
2  FORMULA NEEDED
```

As you can see, I need to enter formula

My effort is this

From the current cell (A2), get the table title, which is in A1.

```
=ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())
```

(I've chosen to use `COLUMN` because I'll eventually have more than 1 column)

Great, that returns `Purchases`

According to the Excel syntax, this references a cell from another worksheet.

='Purchases'!B4

As such, I need to just combine them... This *should* mean what I want is

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())!$B4)
```

But if fails, giving me `#REF!`

What am I doing wrong? I can see I'm missing the single quotes but I'm now very lost

If I remove the `INDIRECT` it shows `$A$1!$B4`

In my real application, I'm using dates (in the above example, I used `purchases`) so this is a screen shot

[image]

When I try to evaluate, it goes through these steps

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&"!$B4$")
```

then

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,3)&"!$B4$")
```

then

```
=INDIRECT("$C$1"&"!$B4$")
```

then

```
=INDIRECT("$C$1!$B4$")
```

then

```
#REF!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just a few improvement:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&"!$B4$")`

Comment: When I try this, I get a prompt from Excel explaining that `There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula?......`

Comment: `"` was missing, I've corrected it now.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, exactly the same issue as I described :( I now see `#REF!` I updated my post with a screen shot. The formula is for the C2 cell (the cell which shows REF)

Comment: please try to [evaluate your formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to see where it fails.

Comment: Updated my post. Thank you for heling so much